# Type hinting a Python contextmanager with arguments

Tags: python, type-hinting, contextmanager

I have the following context manager:

```py
@contextmanager
def timed_task(task_name: str, **context_info)
     pass
```

Now I have the function that

```
def my_func(my_timed_task: Any):
     with my_timed_task("my_func_task", foo="bar"):
          pass
```

How would I type hint `my_func` so that it knows `my_timed_task` is a context manager of type `timed_task(task_name: str, **kwargs)`, or any equivalent context manager with the same arguments?

I know about `contextlib.AbstractContextManager` but I could find documentation that explains how to use it with the conjunction of contextmanager arguments, instead of just argumentless context managers.

Answer (score 1):

So I am making a few assumptions here to provide a complete answer. If any of them are incorrect, you will have to adjust the code accordingly. I assume:

- Your `timed_task` and `my_func` both can return any type.
- Your `**context_info` kwargs can be any type.

One thing that is important to understand here, is that your decorated function itself is **not** the context manager. It is a **factory** function that **returns** a context manager, i.e. an object that has its `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods defined for usage in a `with`-statement. (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager))

In the matter at hand, you basically have two choices.

The **first** one that is technically the "most correct" in my opinion, but may also be overkill in your situation as well as in many other situations, is defining your own [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) first:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager, AbstractContextManager
from typing import Any, Protocol


class MyContextManagerFactory(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, task_name: str, **context_info: Any) -> AbstractContextManager[Any]: ...


@contextmanager
def timed_task(task_name: str, **context_info: Any) -> Any:
    pass


def my_func(my_timed_task: MyContextManagerFactory) -> Any:
    with my_timed_task("my_func_task", foo="bar"):
        pass
```

This has `mypy` pass (in `--strict` mode) without a problem.

The reason a protocol is needed here, is because you have arbitrary keyword arguments `**context_info` allowed in your context manager factory, and to my knowledge it is currently not possible to specify a `Callable` type accordingly.

The benefit of being this pedantic with your types is that an IDE like PyCharm will give you precise hints not only about what arguments of what type are allowed when calling `my_timed_task`, but actually about the full signature including the parameter names, which is neat.

Your **second** option is far simpler, but also less precise. You can simply define the type of `my_timed_task` as a callable accepting anything and returning your context manager:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager, AbstractContextManager
from typing import Any, Callable


@contextmanager
def timed_task(task_name: str, **context_info: Any) -> Any:
    pass


def my_func(my_timed_task: Callable[..., AbstractContextManager[Any]]) -> Any:
    with my_timed_task("my_func_task", foo="bar"):
        pass
```

Also makes `mypy` happy. However there is no information about what arguments your `my_timed_task` factory accepts, so your IDE will not complain about doing something like this:

```py
def my_func(my_timed_task: Callable[..., AbstractContextManager[Any]]) -> Any:
    with my_timed_task(1, 3, "a", True):
        pass
```

Which one of those options you choose is obviously up to you and depends on how precise you want to be.

Hope this helps.